# Laravel - npm install - npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated

Tags: php, laravel-5, npm

I want to start a project by Laravel and Reactjs.
For the first I installed a fresh Laravel project, and then run this commend in the project library

```
npm install
```

but I got this message and no any more progress.

```
 npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5
```

how i can fix this?

Comment: You have to follow the link the error gave you :  https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5

Comment: but this not help me

Comment: Is Laravel up to date ? Check the version

Answer (score 0):

Though it is not a permanent solution, Try yarn https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install

"yarn isntall" instead of "npm install"
then you can use "npm run dev" or whatever command you need.